# Format the following string?

Tags: java, regex, string, escaping

I get the username from Windows Authentication in my application. The username format is Domain\username. How can I get only the username and not the Domain.

For Example: If I have a username as "ABCD\ricky", how can I get only ricky from it.

Comment: This is something very well-documented.  Google it.

Comment: @Ritesh try this: [Java String Split Example](http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example), but remember as pointed out below that the "\" character needs to be escaped properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = string.substring(string.indexOf("\\") + 1);
```

Comment: I guess the above String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote. And even if I add another backslash like string.substring(string.indexOf("\\") + 1); I only get icky, but not ricky

Comment: @Ritesh: You need to verify that, if the original string is a literal, you need to escape the backslash, or else the substring `\r` will be considered a new line character.